# Is there a notation for types?

Tags: terminology, notation, types

Is there a notation for statements like the following:

> If both operands are of type `int`, then the result is of type `int`. If either operand is of type `float`, then the result is of type `float`.

e.g. for the first case, can I say something like:
$$int \ \text{op} \ int \rightarrow int$$

where $\text{op}$ is an operator with the above semantics.

I think I've come across this sort of notation before, but I'm not sure if it has a name or how to express the second scenario (*either* operand is a float).

Answer (score 2):

In looking at

`int op int→int`

my focus is immediately drawn to `→`.

If you have ever studied [Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) and how it forms the foundation of many functional programming languages then you will come to understand  `→` which should not be confused with `→ᵦ` or `→ₐ` . Since searching for `→` is not easy search for [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) instead.

When [Alonzo Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alonzo_Church) invented Lambda Calculus it did not have types. Within a few years [typed Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus) was created. Since many functional languages derive from typed Lambda Calculus you often see type definitions like `int -> int -> int`.

While I don't fully understand your question I suspect this is what you seek

[Specialized type systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Specialized_type_systems)

If you want to spend the rest of your life on this then see

[So many data types, so little time](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/940/5)

---

> how to express the second scenario (either operand is a float).

Since you did not give a specific programming language I would expect something like

`int -> float -> float` and `float -> int -> float`

Comment: Right, the OP is looking for intersection types. I suspect they are trying to type an arithmetic operator such as addition. 

Standard notations for intersections are $\&$ and $\cap$, though I typically wouldn't expect to see the word $\mathit{and}$. 

See page 7 [here](https://users.cs.northwestern.edu/~stamourv/papers/numeric-tower.pdf) for an example.

Comment: In more detail, we can think of the type $\mathit{int} \to \mathit{float} \to \mathit{float}$ as denoting the set of all functions taking an $\mathit{int}$ and a $\mathit{float}$ to a $\mathit{float}$, and $\mathit{float} \to \mathit{int} \to \mathit{float}$ as the functions taking a $\mathit{float}$ and an $\mathit{int}$ to a $\mathit{float}$. A function which does both then has type $(\mathit{int} \to \mathit{float} \to \mathit{float})~\&~(\mathit{float} \to \mathit{int} \to \mathit{float})$

Comment: @KevinClancy I typically wouldn't expect to see the word *and*.  *and* was not meant as an operator with the type specification. In programming in several functional programming languages and knowing about numerical methods I wanted to avoid a discussions about returning values from functions that could use both integer and float values as it can lead you into a false sense of validity, i.e. numerical instability. I prefer to do symbolic math when possible leaving the terms as variables until the calculation of a value is needed. Continued.

Comment: Think [Theano](https://theano-pymc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use union/intersection types: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5653678/781723.

Haskell type classes can be used to support this, but with some significant restrictions: https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/introduction-to-haskell/5-type-classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a new union type as
$$ \mathrm{type} \; number = int \; | \; float $$
Then, you can write down your function
$$ addition : number \rightarrow number \rightarrow number $$